# Google App Engine push to deploy from GitHub for Windows (and git bash)

Tags: git, google-app-engine, github, github-for-windows

Push to deploy from Github (Windows application) to GAE is not working as expected. The repository is accessible through Google Developer but never seems to actually deploy.

Process I followed:

1. I created a new app in GAE.
2. I created a GitHub repository that I sync locally using Github for Windows.
3. In this repository I have copied across and committed a working GAE application (and confirmed it does run locally from the local dir)
4. I changed the app.yaml 'application:' to the new app name.
5. I created a Release Pipeline - Deploy source only
6. I made a change to the readme.md file and committed the change and the synced (which I assume is the same as push?)
7. The app URL gives a 404 and when I go to Computer > App Engine > Instances it says I have no active instances. All the files and history from the GitHub repository are available in Source Code > Browse.

I eventually deployed the app using Google App Engine Launcher and it works online but still cannot update any code by pushing to GitHub using Github for Windows. Repository is still updating in Source Code > Browse.

It seems to GAE-Github connection works but Google does not recognise it as an application?

Please let me know if I have missed something. Cheers.

Update:
I have successfully committed and push using git bash with same result as GitHub for Windows.

Update 2: I have pushed the repository to the Google cloud option (https://source.developers.google.com/p/...) with same result - source visible but not deploying. So I have tried two different applications and two different web based repositories with no luck.

Update 3: I can now deploy via git bash via the Google Cloud Repository but it still does not work as expected when using GitHub. Just updates files and does not deploy.

Comment: I am also having this problem with BitBucket and GitHub. Neither will deploy the app just update the files.

Comment: Good to know you can reproduce the problem. I am using the Google repository option at the moment but hope to have the GitHub option available when this is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved part of my problem. It is not related to this process directly.

My app.yaml file had an error.

Original line: 'threadsafe: yes'

Correction: 'threadsafe: true'

Seems that the App Engine Launcher did not mind the error but Push to Deploy does.

I can now deploy via git bash to the Google Cloud but it still does not work as expected when using GitHub. Just updates files and does not deploy.